# How to bind data with select2 using ng-model?

Tags: jquery-select2

I've set branchInfo.share_product=['X1','S1'] in js, and I want to use below code to bind the selected options with  ['X1','S1'].

```
<select ui-select2 id="share_product_edit" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" tabindex="-1" ng-model="branchInfo.share_product">
    <option ng-repeat="project in products" value="{{project.project}}">{{project.project}}</option>
</select>
```

What I want to achieve is:
[image]

But it shows like (just show "placeholder" value):
[image]